Free Historical Weather Data Download
I am looking for historical weather data (min and max temp, humidity, wind speed, wind direction, precipitation) for specific GPS coordinates. The data must be preferably hourly, but if only daily averages are available that would also do. I want data from 1 Feb 2023 till today.
Preferably I would like to download via RStudio, straight from a website, or from Google Earth Engine or similar platforms. I don't know very well how to code in languages other than R, so please help if other language is needed for the download. Thanks

There are for example ERA5 data available: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=overview with spatial resolution of 0.25 degree and temporary of 1 hour. Example of download and usage in R in https://gsapijaszko.github.io/open_data/environments.html#era5-hourly-data
